# How to find the highest and the lowest averages using 2D arrays in c programming?

Tags: c, arrays, string, 2d, average

there's a mistake in my code but i can't find where. it must calculate the averages after reading inputs.
it reads all the code and gets all the inputs but when it comes to calculating the average it does nothing. help please

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int students, modules, m, n, first_student, last_student, l = 0;
    float student[100][20], high = 0, low = 20, average[students], average_mark[students];
    printf("Please enter the number of students:\n");
    scanf("%d", &students);
    printf("Please enter the number of modules:\n");
    scanf("%d", &modules);

    for (m = 0; m < students; ++m) {
        for (n = 0; n < modules; n++) {
            printf("Please enter the mark of module %d for student number %d,\n", n + 1, m + 1);
            scanf("%f", &student[m][n]);
        }
    }

    for (m = 0; m < students; ++m) {
        average[m] = 0;
    }

    for (n = 0; n < modules; n++) {
        average[m] += student[m][n];
        average_mark[m] = average[m] / modules;
    }

    printf("student     average\n");

    for (m = 0; m < students; ++m) {
        printf("%d     %f\n", m + 1, average_mark[m]);
    }

    for (m = 0; m < students; ++m) {
        if (average_mark[m] < low) {
            average_mark[m] = low;
        }
        else
            if (average_mark[m] == low) {
                last_student = m + 1;
            }

        if (average_mark[m] > high) {
            average_mark[m] = high;
        }
        else
            if (average_mark[m] == high) {
                first_student = m + 1;
            }
    }

    printf("The student who had the highest mark is %d : %f\n", first_student, high);
    printf("The student who had the lowest mark is %d : %f\n", last_student, low);

    for (m = 0; m < students; ++m) {
        if (average_mark[m] == 10 || average_mark[m] > 10) {
            l++;
        }
    }

    printf("the number of students having a mark that equals or exceeds the average is %d\n", l);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `warning: variable 'students' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]` - you can't declare `average[students]` and later read it via `scanf()`.

Comment: The problem lies in the third `for` loop. You iterate through `n` but not `m`.  Either that third loop needs revision or you failed matching brackets in previous (2nd) and / or next (4th) `for` loop. Most probably, that 3rd `for` loop needs to be embraced within the 2nd `for` loop.

Comment: @ssd can you explain more or re-write that part correctly please?

Comment: The loop with `average[m]=0` is finished before the loop with the iteration over `n` will start. Could it be that the following loop was expected to be in the previous loop? After setting average to 0?

Comment: @reichhart yes it is

Comment: And please, the very first comment (@reichhart's) needs to be taken into account as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some other problems in the code but as a start, you may take a peek below.

edit: The next (2nd) problem noted & corrected. I'm leaving you to find & correct the last (3rd) problem.

```
// either these values need to be predefined
// or you'll need to dynamically allocate
// arrays using malloc

int MAX_STUDENTS = 100;
int MAX_MODULES = 20;

int main() {
    int students, modules, m, n, first_student, last_student, l = 0;
    float student[MAX_STUDENTS][MAX_MODULES], high = 0, low = 20, average[MAX_STUDENTS], average_mark[MAX_MODULES];
 
...
...
...

// the 2nd & 3rd for loops needs to be nested as below
    for (m = 0; m < students; ++m) { // this was 2nd
        average[m] = 0;

        for (n = 0; n < modules; n++) { // this was 3rd
            average[m] += student[m][n];
        }

        // you need to move this line out of 3rd loop
        average_mark[m] = average[m] / modules; 
    }

...
...
...
// this is how you find the lowest & highest ranking students
    for (m = 0; m < students; ++m) {
        if (average_mark[m] < low) {
            low = average_mark[m];
            last_student = m;
        }

        if (average_mark[m] > high) {
            high = average_mark[m];
            first_student = m;
        }
    }

    printf("The student who had the highest mark is %d : %f\n", first_student + 1, high);
    printf("The student who had the lowest mark is %d : %f\n", last_student + 1, low);

...
...
...
}
```

Comment: can you please try the code if it works for you after adding your modifications? because it still doesn't work for me